# Mocha test not recognised by VS2019 when a module is included

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, mocha.js, visual-studio-2019, extension-methods

I have a module that contains an extension method. The method extends a dom library class (such as HTMLCollection, HTMLElement). When I include that module into a mocha test and compile the project, I can't see the test method on the test explorer until I remove the module import (it works well with Array extension methods). Can anyone help me to fix up this issue please?

Sample code of the extension method :

```
interface HTMLCollection {
    toArray<T>(): Array<T>;
}

HTMLCollection.prototype.toArray = function () {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        var item = this.item(index);
        result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sample test method code:

```
//following line imports the module that contains extension method
import "html-extensions"; // when i comment out this line this test will be visible on the test explorer 
const assert = require('assert');

describe("Tests", () => {
    it("1st test", () => {

    });
});
```

The following extension method (and more extension for Array) works well with the mocha tests

```
interface Array<T> {
        where(func: Function): Array<T>;
}

    Array.prototype.where = function (func) {
        var result = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
            if (func(this[index], index) == true) {
                result.push(this[index]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: When test discovery starts i get following console output from Tests

[7/10/2020 1:52:24.787 PM] ---------- Discovery started ----------
Processing: C:\Users....\source\repos\html-extensions\html-extensions\test\HTMLCollectionTest.js
Using default Mocha settings
**Test discovery error: ReferenceError: HTMLCollection is not defined**
at Object. (C:\Users....\source\repos\html-extensions\html-extensions\impl\HTMLCollection.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object. (C:\Users....\source\repos\html-extensions\html-extensions\test\HTMLCollectionTest.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10) in C:\Users....\source\repos\html-extensions\html-extensions\test\HTMLCollectionTest.js
Discovered 0 test cases.
No test is available in C:\Users....\source\repos\html-extensions\html-extensions\html-extensions.njsproj. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[7/10/2020 1:52:27.145 PM] ========== Discovery finished: 0 tests found (0:00:02.3403619) ==========

shortly i get **Test discovery error: ReferenceError: HTMLCollection is not defined** error but dom library is also added in tsconfig.ts